# Please help me figure out my hack?

Tags: email-spoofing

new here and a noob but need some help identifying some things I find very strange on my device. Anybody willing to try help figuring out some problems with me, your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We are not tech support. It sounds like you need to take your device to someone for an investigation.